# Visual Studio 2010 looks "zoomed in"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dpi

Today, I installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional on a new laptop with a fresh Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit install. I, being quite used to the look of Visual Studio 2010, instantly spotted that something was wrong. It seems that the Visual Studio application is "zoomed in", in a way. The text is much larger (even though it says that the zoom level is 100%, and the text size is 10, which is the same as what I used before), and generally, so are the other windows like the Solution Explorer and Output console. The quality of the icons and images is also very bad.

Here are two comparison images (I wasn't allowed to post images, so some links will have to do):

This is the look that I'm used to. I see plenty of text in the windows, and the icons are fine.

http://i51.tinypic.com/2mq8dau.png

This is what greeted me when I installed VS2010 on my new laptop. The icons look stretched, and I can fit a lot less code in the window.

http://i56.tinypic.com/35k0fo4.png

The screen resolution on my old computer is 1920x1200 and the resolution on my new computer is 1920x1080. (I resized the VS window on my old computer to about 1920x1080 to show the difference).

It looks like my image host resized the images as well, but you should still be able to see the difference.

Has anyone had the same problem? I'm hoping it's just some visual settings. If anything is missing, I will be happy to provide more information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the same dpi settings for both windows machines? If you don't know how to check this go to this tutorial I googled: http://bit.ly/mlam91

Comment: Try going to Control Panel and selecting View By: "Large Icons" on the right. Click into Display and make sure the size of the text is set to Smaller - 100% (default) on the laptop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems your Font Size DPI is at 150% on the second screenshot. If you right click on the Desktop and select **Personalize** > **Adjust Font Size (DPI)*** you should be able to see what it is currently set at.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when I read the description, and the screenshots confirmed it. The dead giveaway is that the entire UI is enlarged, not just Visual Studio. See for instance the title bar, which is drawn by Windows.

Comment: That was it! Thanks, it looks much better now.

Answer (score 2):

Check

1. that your screen is at native resolution (there can only be one, the native max)
2. that your OS font is

   1. at normal size
   2. antialiasing (i believe windows calls that cleartype or something)
   3. the screen density is 'standard' (usually 96DPI IIRC)

I strongly suspect the latter (the DPI setting). It's under

```
Desktop Properies
Display Properties
Display Settings
Advanced
DPI Settings
```

in my Windows

Answer (score 1):

If you hold down Ctrl and roll the wheel on the mouse it will zoom it in and out. You can then get the desired size that you want. I hope that solves it.

EDIT:

Also if you go to Tools->Options and then under Environment->Font and Colors you can then customize the font size for the whole application.

Comment: I don't believe that's it - in both screenshots it says 100%. I think Sahat's suggestion is more likely to be on the money here.

Comment: I still don't think that's likely to be the answer. A stock Visual Studio install showing it being *generally* larger than expected isn't likely to be a setting within Visual Studio at all.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any setting that could case this effect.

Did you try reseting the settings of visual studio (Tools - Import and Export Settings) or Import the settings of your working maschine.

Maybe you have configured big-icons / big-font in windows?